# When experimenting with fine-tuning CNN models, how do I decide on a suitable head network to attach to the model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm experimenting with training models on a dataset containing images of plant diseases symptoms.

I trained VGG16 model from scratch and also used transfer learning.

In transfer learning I removed the head of the VGG16 model pre-trained on imagenet dataset. Then I connected this custom head to it.

```
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.layers.core import Dense
head_model = base_model.output
head_model = Flatten(name='flatten')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(256,activation='relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dropout(0.5)(head_model)
# Add a softmaxc layer
head_model = Dense(len(class_names),activation='softmax')(head_model)
```

I froze all the layers in the base model and trained the head for around 25 epochs.

Then I unfroze some of the layers at the end of the base model and trained for another 100 epochs.

This lead to more accuracy than training from scratch.

I want to experiment with ResNet50 model as well.

My question is how do I determine a suitable head section to attach? For the above, I got the head architecture from a tutorial. But I don't really understand the reasoning behind it. For example, no CONV layers are used there. Only Dense, Flatten and Dropout. Why are no CONV layers used?

How do I decide on a suitable head for ResNet?

**EDIT**

I have 100-1500 images per class. There are altogether 10 classes.

Training accuracy for resnet

After warmup. Here, I freeze all the base model layers and only train the custom head for 25 epochs.

```
[INFO] evaluating after initialization...
                                        precision    recall  f1-score   support

          Tomato___Tomato_mosaic_virus       0.00      0.00      0.00       532
                 Tomato___Early_blight       0.00      0.00      0.00       239
                  Tomato___Late_blight       0.00      0.00      0.00       470
                    Tomato___Leaf_Mold       0.00      0.00      0.00       238
               Tomato___Bacterial_spot       0.00      0.00      0.00       435
                  Tomato___Target_Spot       0.00      0.00      0.00       362
Tomato___Tomato_Yellow_Leaf_Curl_Virus       0.30      1.00      0.46      1355
                      Tomato___healthy       0.00      0.00      0.00        98
           Tomato___Septoria_leaf_spot       0.00      0.00      0.00       414
      Tomato___Two-spotted_spider_mite       0.00      0.00      0.00       397

                           avg / total       0.09      0.30      0.14      4540
```

After warmup is complete I tried unfreezing some layers gradually. These are the results.

Layers starting from 165 unfrozen. (ran for 60 epochs)

```
425/425 [==============================] - 233s 548ms/step - loss: 0.2656 - accuracy: 0.9201 - val_loss: 93.4192 - val_accuracy: 0.2998
```

Layers from 161 unfrozen (ran for around 50 epochs)

```
425/425 [==============================] - 221s 521ms/step - loss: 0.2627 - accuracy: 0.9235 - val_loss: 91.5139 - val_accuracy: 0.1066
```

Layers from 168 unfrozen (ran for 50 epoch)
val_accuracy = 0.30198

So, val_accuracy increases very rarely. And it decreases also.

In contrast vgg16 gets very good accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any defined CNN models like VGG16, Resnet, Inception and much more have a well-tried architecture, based on hours of training and experiments. Hence generally one does not need to change the present architecture or add any more CONV layers to it. The only difference required is the change in Fully Connected Layers or in simple words the "Head". Since the head is only working on numbers, up to 2 dense layers are more than enough in most of the cases. I have observed models getting heavy (More training time and memory) if we use more than 2 dense layers

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The vgg16 model gave 0.96+ validation accuracy with the head above. I warmed up the head for 25 epochs and then unfroze layers starting from 15 and trained for 100 more epochs. 

But when I tried doing the same with resnet50 validation accuracy would not improve beyond 0.4. Even after unfreezing layers from 158. Why the difference? Should I unfreeze more layers in the top?

Comment: In this case, I will need some more information like whats the training accuracy in the case of resnet50?. What is the image size? how many training images are there?

Comment: it looks like your head is getting overfit. Can I suggest training your ResNet50 model completely without any layer frozen? This might take some time. Since VGG16 is working fine I think ResNet50 is quite too big. I assume your image is RGB and at least 224X224. If not ResNet50, you can try ResNet18

Comment: I'm resizing the images to 224x224. They are originally larger than that. So, should I unfreeze all the resnet layers at once?

Comment: yes we can try that. and I dont see the need warming up the layers also. As its transfer learning.

Answer (score 0):

It's very subjective choosing the ***How do I decide on a suitable head for ResNet?*** or any other Well known architecture. Try not to change the architecture but play with **head node**. I prefer using **GlobalAveragePooling2D()**

One advantage of global average pooling over the fully connected layers is that it is more native to the convolution structure by enforcing correspondences between feature maps and categories. Thus the feature maps can be easily interpreted as categories confidence maps.

And the fully connected layers are prone to overfitting, thus hampering the generalization ability of the overall network.

```
def add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes):
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(1024)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = Dense(512)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    # Creating final model
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    return model
```